# How to appear an error when user key-in specific symbol in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to appear an error when user key-in specific symbol in jQuery? or in another meaning is backend is not allow/not accept the symbol.

The symbols are `\` and `"`

Example user input using input box and `textarea`.

[image]

I am trying to do like this but not help

```
$('#addRemark').change(function(){
    if ($('#addRemark').text() == "'&#34'" || $('#addRemark').text() == '&#92;'){
        alert('Cannot contain symbol \ or "')
    }
});

$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
    if ($("input[type='text']").val() == '"\"' || $("input[type='text']").val() == '"'){
        alert('Cannot contain symbol \ or "')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) methods to check the `\` OR `"` in your text-area input `value`.

Since `\` is reserved word in `JS` so we need to use simple `regex` to check for that. And for this `"` we can use `indexOf` method.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$('#addRemark').on('input', function() {
  if ($(this).val().match(/\\$/) || $(this).val().indexOf('"') >= 0) {
    alert('Cannot contain symbol \ or "')
    //do something if the values contains \ OR "
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="addRemark" cols="50" rows="4" placeholder="Type Something"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is working but the alert will appear after I click outside the textarea. How to make it automatic triggered during typing the symbol in the textarea?

Comment: @mastersuse Please check my edited answer. all working as soon as you type the character. It will show the alert.

Comment: Perfect! I ticked your answer. Thank you

Comment: @mastersuse Thanks alot :) Glad to have helped you. Happy coding

Comment: Hi just want to know, what is the term for `on('change')`, `on('click')` if I want to google it? it is a handler? event? sorry newbie question.

Comment: @mastersuse Sure. Its called the [.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method in jQuery which is a replacement of older function like `live`, `delegate` -  It is used assign direct or event delegation on HTML element via jQuery - you can click on the link above i added there is brief detail about it :)